# dart authentication system with nosql database

Tags: mongodb, dart, couchdb

i am planing to write a dart web application with user authentication system, i mean with sign up,sign in and etc.

For managing user information i need a database, i am thinking about to use nosql database. I was searching in internet and found two very interesting nosql database, mongodb and couchdb.

Now my question, which one of them should i choose and which provide a good driver api for dart? I hear about riak too, but i think it is not so popular like mongodb or couchdb.

Comment: Ask yourself this, why do you think you need NoSQL? Are you going to have gazillions or reads/writes a day? What kind of queries will you need to run? You will need to provide much more information on your expected usage scenarios before anyone can give any coherent advice on this.

Comment: Couple more questions. Do you need a flexible schema, have you read about the CAP theorem and it's implications with regards to MongoDB, CouchDB, etc.

Comment: i hear good stuff about nosql database, it is high scalable and easy to use, but if it makes sense to use against common sql, i do not know.
I am planing to have 10000 users to manange.

Comment: NoSQL is great, but it is for certain use cases. 10,000 users isn't necessarily very much. It depends on how much data you have on them. How many similtaneous reads/write a day? Do you need mobile, how much replication, do you need master-master, master-slave, what types of queries. There are many variables.

Comment: i need high scalable database technology, today it will manage 10000 users, but in few years it would be more users, hopefully. About read/write operations, it would be a lot, because it will be a social network, inclusive where you can upload images. So i need opinions, what is the best for my web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know if you really need a noSql data base but for me the easier to use is mongoDB. The documentation is good and you can find many implementation.

You can find a package here : [mongo_dart](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mongo_dart)
It's pretty simple to use :

```
import 'package:mongo_dart/mongo_dart.dart';

Future<String> getBlogData([String category = '']) {
    print(category);
    Completer c = new Completer();
    _db = new Db("mongodb://127.0.0.1/mysite");
    _db.open().then((o) {
       String data = "[";
       DbCollection collections = this._db.collection("blog_post");
       collections.find(where.sortBy("_id", descending: true)).forEach((v) {
          print(v.runtimeType);
          data += JSON.encode(v) + ",";
       }).then((e) {
         data = data.substring(0, data.length-1);
         data += "]";
         c.complete(data);
       });
     });
    return c.future;
 }

void main() {
    getBlogData("news").then(print);
}
```

Comment: I'm not convinced either, but I agree MongoDB is nice to use.